# Convert plain text to array

Tags: php

If I get the following text string from mysql (or whatever) how can I convert it to an actual array using PHP?

```
array("foo" => "bar","honey" => "pops")
```

I know I can save an array in a serialized state, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid here.

Comment: You can `eval()` it, but only do so with _extreme_ caution.

Comment: *Never* put PHP code in your database.  Use JSON, or a serialized object (why do you want to avoid this?).

Comment: rocket is damn right, eval is evil :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "don't do this".  *Never* put PHP code in your database.  The database is for *data*, not code.

The *correct* way is to store a serialized array (not sure why you'd want to avoid that).

Comment: @dqhendricks: I agree, but I don't know where that data is coming from, so this is what I'd suggest for now.

Comment: @dqhendricks The only reason I wanted to avoid storing serialized data is for convenience (normal arrays are easier to write), but it's obviously not worth it. And using multiple tables to store the related data is definitely **not** lucrative for this project, and I can think of many other situations where this would be this case, too.

Comment: @natli: You can write JSON, that's easy :-)

Comment: @dqhendricks Yeah, I get that, but that's not even remotely what I'm doing here. The serialized array is sent to a C# socket server, which will execute code based on what's in said array, and post back results to PHP. Those results are then put back in to the database, and whoever requested the data (**not me**) knows what to do with it. The data that's in the serialized array that is sent to the server, never needs to be accessed after creation. Do you really think it's wise to create a new mysql field for each element anyone is possibly planning to send to the socket server? >.<

Comment: @natli: In your case, it seems saving serialized arrays (or JSON) in the database is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` but it is too dangerous .... **I DON'T ADVICE YOU USE SUCH**

```
$string = '$array = array("foo" => "bar","honey" => "pops");' ;
eval($string);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array(2) {
    ["foo"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["honey"]=>
    string(4) "pops"
}
```

### Recommendation

use standard formats such as

`JSON` http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

`XML` http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

`Serialized PHP`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Try something like this:

```
$my_string = 'array("foo" => "bar","honey" => "pops")';

eval("\$result=$my_string;");
```